# List all combinations but with restriction

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I've found the way to list all possible combinations of n elements grouped in sets of k elements. From maths, number is easy: n!/(k! * (n-k)!) and python code is really simple using itertools:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a,3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

But how to implement a restriction like: list only groups with only m elements in common ? so in previous example, for m=1, result should be:

```
[(1, 2, 3)]
```

With 5 elements and m=1:

```
>>> b=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(b,3))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

So my result is:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5)]
```

Practical application of this question is how to group people, considering that only m people can repeat in result groups. Idea is to find groups with different people, to avoid groups of 'friends'. Imagine this for an school activity, repeated few days, where we want to ensure avoiding people to repeat with others as much as possible.

Comment: All your tuples in the example have at least two different elements.

Comment: sorry I just can't help it that's just spot on, @KlausD.

Comment: @joanba different elements with respect to what? The first tuple?

Comment: You rephrased it, but it did not get any clearer.

Comment: You answer so fast, just editing post to be more understandable

Comment: What makes your numbers "friends"? Please think how you ask your question! If humans can't understand it, a computer won't understand your instructions as well.

Comment: Idea here is how to group a class of 20 people, in groups of 5 people, but allowing only groups with only 2 people in common. Not sure if this explanation is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop:

```
m = 1
combos = list(itertools.combinations(a,3))
result = []
for combo in combos:
    if result:
        if all([sum([1 for item in combo if item in tup]) == 1 for tup in result]):
            result.append(combo)
    else:
        result.append(combo)
result
#[(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5)]
```

This way you will be able to control number of mutual members and get desired output.

Comment: @erhesto and completely correct, yet I wrote new names for variables.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `for` loop to compare first combination with rest (using set intersection function `"&"`):

```
def getsets(a, n):              # FUNCTION FOR THIS PURPOSE
    combos = list(itertools.combinations(a,n))  # GET ALL COMBINATIONS
    print(combos[0])            # PRINT FIRST COMBINATION
    for i in combos[1:]:        # FOR EACH OF REST
        if len(set(combos[0]) & set(i)) == 1:       # IF ONLY 1 ITEM COMMON WITH INITIAL
            print(i)            # PRINT IT
```

Testing:

```
getsets([1,2,3,4], 3)
print("---------")
getsets([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)   # INITIAL SET ONLY
---------
(1, 2, 3)   # INITIAL SET
(1, 4, 5)   # ONLY '1' IS COMMON WITH FIRST SET
(2, 4, 5)   # ONLY '2' IS COMMON WITH FIRST SET
(3, 4, 5)   # ONLY '3' IS COMMON WITH FIRST SET
{1, 2, 3}   # ONLY '4' IS COMMON WITH FIRST SET
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be, that logical equivalent of result that you've got is something like this:

```
a = range(1,6)
shared_elem_count = 1
group_count = 3

combinations = itertools.combinations(a, group_count)
results = []

for combination in combinations:
    res_union = set().union(*results)
    intersection = set(combination).intersection(res_union)
    if len(intersection) <= shared_elem_count:
        results.append(combination)
```

As in your example tuples don't share more than m common elements with any of other available. But as it's pointed in comments, that solution is strictly tide to order of operations. First tuple determines what next tuples would be acceptable.

Mind the fact, that what you said in your comment is a problem which is little broader: grouping `n` people in groups of count `k` that don't have more than `m`people in common will give significantly more solutions than those that we have 'not filtered out'. For example, you've pointed that for `m = 1` and `a = (1,2,3,4,5)` solution is:

```
(1,2,3),(1,4,5)
```

...but actually there is many more solutions, for example:

```
(2,3,4),(1,2,5)
(3,4,5),(1,2,3)
(1,4,5),(2,3,4)
```

So I'm not completely sure if filtering combinations is proper way to solve your problem (nevertheless, it's not very clear *what* actually you'd like to achieve, so who knows).

Comment: (2,3,4) cannot be a solution because it has 2 elements in common with initial solution (1,2,3)

Comment: You never said *what* is initial solution. If you'd order `itertools.combinations(a, group_count)` different way you might get different "initial" solution". What I've listed in my answer is "groups" of solutions actually, (each group has 2 elements) not additional combinations for `(1,2,3),(1,4,5)`.